# Failure after sending push notification to specific IDs with Cloud.PushNotifications.notify

Tags: push-notification, appcelerator, appcelerator-arrow, arrowdb

I've been developing a chat app with Titanium and I'm facing some issues while sending push notifications when a user send a message.

If I simply call:

```
Cloud.PushNotifications.notify({
    channel : 'myChannel',
    to_ids : usersID.toString(),
    payload : {
        message : "message",
        from : myId,
        sound : "default",
        alert : "New message!",
    }
};, function(e) {
        if (e.success) {
            console.log('Success');
        } else {
            console.log('Error:\n' + ((e.error && e.message) || JSON.stringify(e)));
        }
    });
```

I get the OK from the server

```
    {"push_notification":{"id": "xxx", "payload": "{\"message\":\"message\",\"from\":\"xxx\",\"sound\":\"default\",\"alert\":\"New message!\"}", "channel": "myChannel"}, "success": true,"error": false, "meta":{"code": 200, "status": "ok", "method_name": "Notify"}}
```

but the push notification is marked with the status **Failure** on the ArrowDB panel.

A different story if I set `to_ids = "everyone"`, the push is sent (as long as you're an admin user).

The weird thing is that I get the same error if I try to send it from the ArrowDB panel.

**Sending the push with specific IDs**
[image: Sending the push with specific IDs]

**Sending the push to everone**
[image: Sending the push to everone]

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but I tried to stick to the basic examples provided by titanium.

Comment: Experiencing exactly the same thing. Server log returns successful push but the push logs are reporting failure with no further details

Comment: I just remembered that I fixed this in another project, I will be updating with the answer later on. It was something to do with the method I was calling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the devices didn't have an user associated:

[image: user not associated to device]

After a lot of tests I realized that after the `Cloud.Users.login` method I was wrongly calling the method `Cloud.PushNotifications.subscribeToken` instead of the `Cloud.PushNotifications.subscribe`. Changing that, after the login and subscribe, the device has an user associated to it:

[image: user associated to device]

And everything works as expected, push notifications are sent and received.

EDIT:
I didn't notice that hovering the Failure label showed you the reason (a little weird way to show info), and the reason in fact was somewhat explained in there:

[image: error message]

Comment: Still experiencing issues but I think it's related to

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35557691/push-messages-for-ios-error-code-1001-remote-host-closed-connection-during-h/36053980

Comment: have you tried to hover on the Failure label? I found that out from your link and it would've been actually helpful to know that.